# Change java x86 to 64bit on Jenkins server

Tags: java, jenkins, continuous-integration

I'm using Jenkins for CICD. currently Java 32bit is being installed on Jenkins sever but I have problem with node and npm which forced me to use java 64 bit. is there any major impact on my projects in Jenkins if I switch to 64bit?